# Knowing which command was executed in vscode terminal in a vscode extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to run certain methods in my vscode extension when a `git checkout <branch_name>` command is executed. One of the ways that works is through the vscode UI that allows me attach an event listener. But since the user can also update their branch using the terminal using `git checkout ...` how can I trigger some function based on what's executed in the terminal? Is there a way to attach an event listener to the vscode terminal that allows me to know which commands are executed?

Comment: Is your goal that something is run on your local machine on checkout, or on all machines on checkout?

Comment: just on the user's local machine

Comment: Then you might want to look into git hooks. There is one called `post-checkout`. Maybe you could do something there which your extension reacts to.
If you know any open source extensions which you know reacts to it you could also look into how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a watcher on the `<project_root>/.git/HEAD` using chokidar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar)  worked for me!